# Joining two interrogative sentences with coordinating conjunction

Tags: interrogatives

How should I join two interrogative sentences with a coordinating conjunction?

> 1. Should the purpose of our education be focused only on ornamenting students with great degrees or **it should** be focused on equipping students not only with skills but also with moral qualities?
> 2. Should the purpose of our education be focused only on ornamenting students with great degrees or **should it** be focused on equipping students not only with skills but also with moral qualities?

Sentence no. 1: there are two sentences connected with "or" coordinating conjunction. 1st sentence is in interrogative form and 2nd sentence is not interrogative. now, the query is: do both sentences need to be interrogative since they are connected by "or"?  (for example, sentence no. 2: where both sentences are in interrogative form)

Answer (score 2):

Only sentence 2 is correct, for the reason you stated. Additionally, there should be a comma before "or" since it's an independent clause.